# Is there a tool to continuously copy contents of a directory to HDFS as they are?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, etl, flume

I tried using flume directory spooler source and HDFS sink. But this does not serve my purpose because, the files are read by Flume and then get written to HDFS as part files which can be rolled  by size/time (Please correct me if I've got this wrong). 
Is there a tool that continously does something like an HDFS put on all files that are dumped in the spool directory ?

Comment: you can configure the roll properties to 0 so i won't get split

Answer (score -1):

If i got your question correctly then you have a and you are getting files into it and that file you want to move to **HDFS** without reading it and **HDFS** **copyFromLocal** will solve your issue then you just need to have an logic which can return you the recent files in the directory and run **CopyFromLocal** command to copy it in **HDFS**.